# Calculate array with operators

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am building a calculator app. Where I store input values in array with operators.
e.g

```
let arr = ['2', '3', '+', '7', '-', '8', '*', '2']
```

I can't figure out how to handle operator by looping over to get result either 44 or 14 depends on logic.

Comment: eval(arr.join(''))

Comment: https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

Comment: _"...depends on logic"_ - The math is quite clear what the correct result should be.

Comment: @Andreas depends, if you type it on a calculator it would not wait for order of operations.

Comment: Eval is not recommended to use